# Como e onde adicionar imagem pelo Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Qual pasta colocar as imagens que quero adicionar no meu aplicativo? Na drawable?

E como adicionar através do **Android Studio**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Usando o `Android Studio 1.5`:

- Botão direito do mouse em **res**, novo ***Image Asset***
- No **Tipo de Recurso**, escolha **Barra de Ação e Ícones de Tabulação**
- Escolha o **Caminho** e dê um nome para sua imagem
- Clique em **Próximo**
- Clique em **Concluir**

---

#### Usando o `Android Studio 2.2` ou superior:

- Botão direito do mouse em **res**, novo ***Image Asset***
- No **Tipo de ícone**, escolha **Barra de Ação e Ícones de Tabulação**
- No **Tipo de recurso**, selecione **Imagem**
- Escolha o **Caminho** e dê um nome para sua imagem
- Clique em **Próximo**
- Clique em **Concluir**

---

#### A imagem será salva na pasta `/res/drawable`

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim na Pasta drawable, é onde deves colocar suas imagens

O que é Drawable?
Um recurso drawable é um conceito geral para um gráfico que pode ser desenhado na tela e que pode ser recuperado com APIs como getDrawable(int) ou ser aplicado a outro recurso XML com atributos como android:drawable e android:icon . Há vários tipos de drawables: Arquivo Bitmap. É um arquivo gráfico de bitmaps.
fonte:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource?hl=pt-br